# Remove Index inside variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have code like this, but how can I remove "1","2","3" inside "collaterals" ?

```
{
   "brokerPartner": "XX",
   "collaterals": {
       "1": {
              "stockCode": "ABC",
              "contractCode": "GE01905438831212",
              "qtyEfek": "900"
            },
       "2": {
              "stockCode": "DEF",
              "contractCode": "GE01905438831212",
              "qtyEfek": "1900"
            },
       "3": {
              "stockCode": "HIJ",
              "contractCode": "GE01905438831212",
              "qtyEfek": "100"
            }
  },
   "dueDate": "2019-08-06",
   "stockType": "S",
   "tradeDate": "2019-08-06"
}
```

I want the following result:

```
"collaterals":{
   {
      "stockCode":"ABC",
      "contractCode":"GE01905438831212",
      "qtyEfek":"900"
   },
   {
      "stockCode":"DEF",
      "contractCode":"GE01905438831212",
      "qtyEfek":"1900"
   },
   {
      "stockCode":"HIJ",
      "contractCode":"GE01905438831212",
      "qtyEfek":"100"
   }
}
```

I'm using laravel 5.6

Comment: You want to turn it into an array of objects removing the keys?

Comment: Please show your desired output

Comment: is that a json format data ?

Comment: yes is that json format..

Comment: What do you want to do - to remove `"1","2","3" inside "collaterals"` or to extract `"collaterals"` from JSON content?

Comment: @Zhorov i want to remove `"1","2","3"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get `collaterals` as an object since a json object has to be indexed, but you can get an array of objects by creating a numeric array from your associative one:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);    
$data['collaterals'] = array_values($data['collaterals']);    
$json = json_encode($data);
```

This will result in `{ "brokerPartner": "XX", "collaterals":[{"stockCode":"ABC", ...}, {"stockCode":"DEF", ...}]}` (most of the string ommited).